# Is it possible to give read permissions to users in sharepoint using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to upload large files to sharepoint using [createUploadSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint.

Is there a way to give read permissions in upload process to a specific user or I have to use other endpoint for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to manage and change permissions of SharePoint online using Microsoft Graph API EndPoints: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Permissions are managed separately through MS Graph End Points designated for permissions: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Another stackover article on the same with slight different issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68007718/issue-with-granting-permissions-to-user-in-sharepoint-using-graph-api)